# Why are my css and div not working properly?

Tags: jquery, css

I want `id="#div3"` to work independently, but it just follows `id="#div1"`. How can I make my third div independent from the first div?  [Here is a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sunny1212/NY2Cb/). You can see the `div3` shadow going down because of `div1`.

Also, when I change `div3` margins, it also changes `div1` and `div2` margins.

Also, I don't want my page to scroll down; I want my image (which is in div3) to hold its position on the lower right corner.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2" align="center"><div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

```
#div1
{
height:190px;
margin-top:-310px;
margin-left:-10px;
width:101%!important;
background-image:url("misty_2copy.jpg");
position:relative;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
z-index:6000;
}

#div1:hover
{
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px teal;
}

#div2
{
height:190px;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:-810px;
background-image:url("Untitled-12.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:relative;
z-index:6500;
}

#div3
{

margin-top:210px;
margin-left:60%;
height:590px;
background-image:url("Untitled-3.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:relative;
}
```

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
    //$("#div2").toggle();
    $("#div1").animate(
    {
        marginTop:000
    },1500,function()
    {
            $("#div2").animate(
    {
    marginLeft:400
    },500,function()
    {});
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be wise to create a demonstration of the problem using jsFiddle (http://jsFiddle.net). Makes it much easier for others to see the problem, and often you will find the solution yourself while creating the fiddle.

Comment: ok i have done it thank you for info

Comment: Please note that, if you have additional questions, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you haven't closed your div tags properly:

```
<div id="div2" align="center"><div>
                         -----^
```

Comment: but it is still animate with the first div ..i mean div3 is still moving on page on the animation of div1

Comment: @RathoreSunny You should validate your markup, most of the times an unclosed tag is the culprit.

Comment: @RathoreSunny As your elements are positioned relatively, margin of the elements changes the position of other elements, you should use `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing slash `</div>` on the second div...

Answer (score 0):

`div2` is inside `div1` 
So close `div1` first, and start `div2`
like this:

```html
<div id="div1"> content goes here</div>
<div id="div2" align="center"> content goes here</div>
<div id="div3"> content goes here</div>
```